# How do I fix the "reencode mismatch" error when using the Gibbed Save Editor?

Tags: borderlands-2

I'm getting a "reencode mismatch" error with the Gibbed Save Editor for Borderlands 2. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

That error message means you are using a version of Gibbed Save Editor that is not compatible with the version of Borderlands 2 you have. If you haven't already, update Borderlands 2 and get the latest version of [Gibbed Save Editor](https://github.com/gibbed/Gibbed.Borderlands2/releases) here.